# Two Level Page Tables - How many entries does the inner PT have?

Tags: operating-system

Given that the logic space is 32 bits and the paging system is that of two level PTs.
Page size is 1KB.
We have a TLB with 4 slots and a PTE is 4B.

How many entries do the inner and outer PTs have? (aka how does the logical address divided?)

Are we able to calculate it or there aren't enough data?

What I've done so far is this:
From the page size we get that the offset is 10bits (2^10 page size).
So we have 32-10 = 22 bits remaining for the inner and outer PTs.

Answer (score 0):

From page size we get offset =10bits.
For number of page, we have - 2^32/2^10 = 2^22 pages.
Since, we have two level paging system, we will page the pages,
 i.e. 2^22 pages will constitute page table entry for next paging so,
It's desirable to fit a 2nd-level page table in one page. So total number of entries in the 2nd-level page is = 2^10 (size of page) / 2^2 (size of one page table entry) = 2^8. 
Now, number of pages in outer page table= 2^22/2^8= 2^14

Therefore, we have 14 bits in outer page table and 22-14=8 bits for inner page table and 10 bits for offset.